# How to make a supervisor in webots with a robot node

Tags: webots

I am doing a project in webots and i dont know how to comunicate a supervisor with my control alredy done. I have seen some questions like this in this forum but i continue as before read it.

I have a controller program for my robot and works fine. I have tried with a robot node and a supervisor node, because sometimes it said that supervisor node is deprecated. And when i run my node of robot that have in their controller my code of supervisor appears:

WARNING: supervisor: The process crashed some time after starting successfully. WARNING: 'supervisor' controller crashed.

Anyone could help me please? Thank you!!

Comment: Sharing your code (or at least the supervisor specific part) would help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but there could be various reasons why your supervisor controller is crashing. Until you clarify your question by posting a more detailed error dump, there is not much we can do to help. Make sure that your Robot node has the supervisor field set to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

----Code control:

```
#include <webots/Robot.hpp>
#include <webots/Motor.hpp>
#include <cmath>

#define TIME_STEP 32

using namespace webots;

int main() {
  
  Robot *robot = new Robot();
  
  Motor *wheels[4];
  char wheels_names[2][8] = {"Patid", "Patdd"};
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    wheels[i] = robot->getMotor(wheels_names[i]);
    //wheels[i]->setPosition(INFINITY);
    //wheels[i]->setVelocity(0.0);
  }
  
  const double F = 2.0;   // frequency 2 Hz
  double t = 0.0;         // elapsed simulation time

  while (robot->step(TIME_STEP) != -1) {
    const double position = 100*sin(t * 2.0 * M_PI * F);
    
    wheels[0]->setPosition(position);
    t += (double)TIME_STEP / 1000.0;
  }

  delete robot;
  return 0;
}
```

-----Supervisor control:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <webots/Supervisor.hpp>
#include <webots/Robot.hpp>
#include <webots/receiver.hpp>

#define TIME_STEP 32

using namespace webots;

int main() {
  Supervisor *supervisor = new Supervisor();

  // do this once only
  Node *robot_node = supervisor->getFromDef("tigre");
  Field *trans_field = robot_node->getField("translation");

  while (supervisor->step(TIME_STEP) != -1) {
    // this is done repeatedly
    const double *values = trans_field->getSFVec3f();
    std::cout << "MY_ROBOT is at position: " << values[0] << ' '
              << values[1] << ' ' << values[2] << std::endl;
  }

  delete supervisor;
  return 0;
}
```

And all the messages errors:

```
WARNING: supervisor: The process crashed some time after starting successfully.
WARNING: 'supervisor' controller crashed.
[frecuency] Warning: "�<B" device not found.
[frecuency] Warning: "�<B" device not found.
WARNING: The current physics step could not be computed correctly. Your world may be too complex. If this problem persists, try simplifying your bounding object(s), reducing the number of joints, or reducing WorldInfo.basicTimeStep.
WARNING: The current physics step could not be computed correctly. Your world may be too complex. If this problem persists, try simplifying your bounding object(s), reducing the number of joints, or reducing WorldInfo.basicTimeStep.
```

I have right now the robot node with the supervisor controller with supervisor field true. However i have tried all configurations with the supervisor field in the robot control and supervisor control and its the same.

By the way, i hasnt got yesterday this error:

[frecuency] Warning: "�<B" device not found.
[frecuency] Warning: "�<B" device not found.

I would be so grateful if you could help me. If you have more questions don´t be shy, i will answer with pleasure

Comment: I have solved the trouble, only was the def name, it wasn´t good. Thank you